"dry gumption" means common sense? Why there is the word 'dry'?

"dry gumption" is one of the meanings defined as common sense in my dictionary.

Why there is the word 'dry'? My dictionary says it is 'common sense or life wisdom'

Can you tell/show us exactly what the dictionary says? I've never heard the expression, and Googling it finds no results.

whatever the DuckDuckGo equivalent of a 'Googlewhack' is, "dry gumption" is one of them. A single result on a blog. We're not looking at a recognised phrase, just two words and their dictionary meanings.

The phrase  "dry gumption" suggests a specific type of common sense or wisdom, with "dry" adding an extra layer of meaning.
Here's a breakdown:


Gumption refers to determination, courage, and practical intelligence.
It implies a combination of guts and common sense needed to tackle challenges effectively.
Synonyms: common sense, good sense,
(Source:  Vocabulary.com)



"Dry" in this context likely modifies "gumption" to emphasize straightforwardness, lack of embellishment, or a practical, no-nonsense quality.
It suggests wisdom that is plain, grounded.

Example Use:.
Someone with "dry gumption" might offer advice or insight in a plainspoken, matter-of-fact way, focusing on practical truths rather than abstract theories.

This is quite a rare phrase with not many hits in Google Books.
dry gumption
The book No Uncertain Terms has a mention of this phrase, and it is grouped with horse sense and common sense.  We can see that they share similar meanings, and they just mean gumption.  There is not much significance in dry.
Edit
With that sole hit in Google Books, the phrase is deemed to have no currency.

When I searched Google Books for "dry gumption" with the constraint thsat I only wanted results where I could at least see the surrounding context, the only result returned was Safire's No Uncertain Terms. Effectively, it has zero currency. It doesn't really make sense to me anyway. We certainly have plenty of dry humour, dry wit, and people making dry observations. But in all those contexts, dry means "droll, imaginatively amusing" - in some ways that's almost the opposite of "stolid, staid, old-fashioned common sense", which is what gumption means to me.

Thanks, @FumbleFingers.  It's indeed hard to think of what that author meaned by dry. M+W sense 12c gives lacking embellishment: plain.  Possible?  So dry gumption just means gumption.
dry

One thing that comes to mind is the letters dry gu occur relatively often in (rural, old-fashioned) American English in the specific case of dry gulch (a dried-up river bed, often where there's only water immediately after a "flash flood"). I don't really think "lacking embellishment" is relevant. But it's got zero currency anyway.

My mother used 'gumption' often, when suggesting that I and ('kids today') lacked it. It seemed to imply initiative and motivation, as well as common sense.
